# Sheetjs reads only first 1000 rows

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

I use sheetjs to import excel-files into a database. Everything works fine, but it just imports the first 1000 rows.

Here's my code:
When the user loads a file in the input field, it creates a worker to do the reading and when done sends it with ajax to the php import-script.

```
$('#input-excel2').change(function(e){
            var v=Date.now();
            var worker = new Worker("./scripts/parsexlsx2.js?v="+v);
            var data= e.target.files[0];
            var filename= e.target.files[0].name;
            if(filecheck(filename)) {
                worker.postMessage(data);
                $('#loader2').jqxLoader('open');
                worker.onmessage = function(e) {
                    $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            url: "./scripts/import2.php?action=import",
                            data: {data: e.data, datei: filename},
                            datatype: "JSON",
                            success: function(answer) {
                                $('#eventsPanel2').html(answer);
                                $("#input-excel2").val("");
                                getlastuploads();
                            }
                        });
                    worker.terminate();
                    $('#loader2').jqxLoader('close');
                };
            } else {
                $('#eventsPanel2').html("Die Datei "+filename+ " wurde bereits importiert!");
            }
        });
```

This is the actual read script in the worker:

```
importScripts('../js-xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js');
onmessage=function(msg) {

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(msg.data);
reader.onerror  = function(e) {
    var htmlstr = e.data;
};
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result); //reader.result;
    var wb = XLSX.read(data,{type:'array',cellDates:true, cellNF: false, cellText:false});
    var sheetName = wb.SheetNames[0];
    var result = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets[sheetName],{header:1,dateNF:'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh:mm:ss'});
    postMessage(result);
};
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself:
Problem was the PHP script. PHP has a Limit set for POST in max_input_vars.
Solution: JSON_stringify the data before sending via POST.